# Syntax Error 'Helper' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, helper

I am building a form where i can drag and drop button controls.

I followed the tutorial from [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31840/Move-Controls-on-a-Form-at-Runtime) but the code generates an error difficult for me to debug.

Syntax Error

> Error code CS1030, "The name 'Helper' does not exist in the current
>   context

I have tried adding and removing namespaces, `using System` and `using System.Drawing` but the same error code is still present.

In a much more extensive code like the [actual example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31840/Move-Controls-on-a-Form-at-Runtime), Helper.ControlMover does work, and it is very easy to use. What exactly am i missing in the code below?

Thank you for your time and help.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace MovingControls
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Helper.ControlMover.Init(this.button1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you put the code that you downloaded for that Helper class?  Did you reference it?

Comment: Create a new class named **ControlMover**. Then paste the content of the ControlMover class from the example link and reference like this **ControlMover.Init(this.button1);**

Comment: I was stuck looking for "Helper" in some namespaces, constructing my own ControlMover class solved the problem. Thank you. In other cases (much larger code), Helper WAS found, but I cannot reproduce the problem for this small example, not  even reproducing the entire using declarations from the larger code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did have a namespace Helper in the large code